# Issue while converting API output to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have API output in the below format.

```
reponse.text

'{"position": {"lat": 1.352083, "lon": 103.819836}, "mapView": {"N": 1.4784001, "E": 104.0945001, "S": 1.1496, "W": 103.594}}\n'
```

I want to convert this output to pandas dataframe .

**My code**

```
import json
d = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Current Output**

```
    position    mapView
E   NaN            104.0945
N   NaN             1.4784
S   NaN             1.1496
W   NaN            103.5940
lat 1.352083        NaN
lon 103.819836      NaN
```

**My Expected Output**

```
lat       lon
1.352083  103.819836
```

How can this be achieved in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. import `json_normalize` from pandas and then you can simply use

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

jsonData = json.loads(response.text)

df = json_normalize(jsonData)
```

print(df)

```
position.lat  position.lon  mapView.N  mapView.E  mapView.S  mapView.W
    1.352083    103.819836     1.4784   104.0945     1.1496    103.594
```

then simply delete extra columns and rename it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
d = json.loads(response.text)

df =pd.DataFrame([d['position']])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are passing as argument the whole dictionary created by the json parser, while you only want to use the position key.

please go check the DataFrame constructor documentation page [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for additional parameters.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> api_resp = json.loads('{"position": {"lat": 1.352083, "lon": 103.819836}, "mapView": {"N": 1.4784001, "E": 104.0945001, "S": 1.1496, "W": 103.594}}\n')
>>> api_resp
{'position': {'lat': 1.352083, 'lon': 103.819836}, 'mapView': {'N': 1.4784001, 'E': 104.0945001, 'S': 1.1496, 'W': 103.594}}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=api_resp['position'], index=[0])
>>> df
        lat         lon
0  1.352083  103.819836
```